# Getting wrong time using NSDateFormatter

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

When i am

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"]
```

using to fetch the current hour
i am getting correct time till 12:59 but after that it again starts from 1:00 i.e. 12:59 is displayed as 12:59 but 14:00 is displyed as 2:00.

Please let me if anyone is also having a similar problem and suggest a solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Please check the code below.

```
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormator = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    dateFormator.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;
    dateFormator.dateFormat=@"HH:mm:ss";
    NSCalendar * calender=[[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:[NSGregorianCalendar autorelease]];
    NSDateComponents * component=[calender components:NSHourCalendarUnit|NSMinuteCalendarUnit fromDate:date];
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"]
```

should give you the time in 24 Hours. But this doesn't work if the user set 24 hour to off. Despite using HH in a format string, the user setting overrides this. This might be the problem in your case!

Comment: I am getting correct display of time with 24 hour format on or off either way. Actually i have shared my app with people across 2 timezones, one of those is having this problem. I have tried changing timezone etc on my mobile but still i am not having this issue. I am getting correct time by using HH formatter

Answer (score 0):

Use this one

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd kk:mm:ss"];
[dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];

NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```

Comment: You will get exact time i hope

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:ss"];
```

HH : 24 hour format

hh : 12 hour format

So in your case

//after conversion to date

if ON

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
```

if OFF

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a"];
```

Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"H:mm"]
```

for 24 hour time format

Answer (score 0):

Set your dateformat to

```
[dateFormatter setDateformat:@"HH:MM a"];
```